# Connecting flight inside the U.S then Canada

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, delta-air-lines, westjet

I will be flying Delta from Las Vegas to Los Angeles and then WestJet Los Angeles to Toronto, the airlines are partners so do I have to check my bag again or they will send them directly to Canada. I will be arriving at Terminal 2 LAX and also leaving from the same terminal.

Comment: Is this a single booking or separate tickets?

Comment: it doesn't matter that they are partners, it matters if you bought one ticket or two tickets

Answer (score 3):

You will need to recheck the bag directly with Westjet at your connecting flight. Source: Delta on Twitter. Conversation screenshotted below.

[image: Twitter conversation]